# Entity Framework Code First связь один-к-одному

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Пишу содержимое класса в базу через EF, описываю через Code First.

```
public class LogRecord
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual LogDelivery LogDelivery {get;set;}
}
public class LogDelivery 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int LogRecordId { get; set; }
    public new ICollection<LogOrder> Orders { get; set; }
    public new ICollection<LogPrintedDoc> ResignDocs { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public virtual LogRecord LogRecord { get; set; }
}
```

Дальше описываются прочие вложения (LogOrder, LogPrintedDoc и т.д.)
Для связей "один-ко-многим", например для связи Delivery-Order, всё работает прекрасно, Id родителя указывается.
Для связи "один-к-одному", т.е. для связи Record-Delivery, в таблицу Delivery в поле RecordId всегда пишется 0.

Вопрос: что не так? Как заставить EF писать RecordId в базу?

Comment: EF пишет в базу то, что Вы помещаете в объект. Если у Вас `LogDelivery.Id == 0`, то 0 и будет записан

Comment: Id - ключ, EF создала его как Identity-поле, само собой я его назначить не могу. Если я всё правильно понимаю, то когда я присваиваю LogRecord.Delivery некое значение у меня должна сформироваться связь между записями в таблицах LogRecord и LogDelivery. Так это работает в отношении связи 1-to-many. Т.е. когда я заполняю Delivery.Orders, делаю SaveChanges - у меня создаются записи в Orders с ссылкой на соответствующие Delivery в поле DeliveryId. А вот в случае с One-to-One ID родителя в базу не пишется. Хотя при создании схемы EF создал все нужные ключи и констрейнты.

Comment: Т.е. в таблице `LogDelivery` `Id` является foreign key? EF это сделал? Что-то я сильно в этом сомневаюсь, более того, это поле не должно быть Identity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В понимании EF, связь один-к-одному - это (по умолчанию) связь по первичным ключам. Свойство `LogRecordId` не используется для связи - а потому всегда 0 (вы же его не заполняете).

Если вас устраивает такая ситуация - просто удалите `LogRecordId`. В противном случае вам придется объяснить EF что именно вы имели в виду:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Entity<LogDelivery>().HasRequired(x => x.LogRecord).WithOptional(x => x.LogDelivery).Map(c => c.MapKey("LogRecordId"));
    }
```

Comment: LogRecordId удалить всё равно придётся - EF, похоже, создаёт это свойство при мэпинге и ругается на то, что оно уже существует. В остальном - заработало, и FK прописались корректно.